# What are Valid Goldberg Polyhedra Frequencies?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, polyhedra

The list of [octahedral Goldberg polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra#Octahedral) $GP_{IV}(n,m)$ looks like the following:

$$
(1,0)\;,(2,0)\;,(3,0)\;,(4,0)\;,(5,0)\;,(7,0)\;,(8,0)\;(9,0)\;,,...\\
(1,1)\;,(2,1)\;,(2,2)\;,(3,3)\;,(4,4)\;...
$$

> Is there a (simple) way to see, which pairs $(n,m)$ are valid frequencies?

I tried to get them via transformations like they are described in the [Construction site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron#Construction), *e.g.*
*"a whirl can transform a GP(a,b) into GP(a+3b,2a-b) for a>b"*, but the number of [operations applicable to a polyhedra is huge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation#Operations_on_polyhedra) and I don't expect them to leave the transformed polyhedra in the octahedral subset.

Knowing that the initial $GP^0$ and the transformed polyhedra $GP^1$ represent bicubic planar graphs some transformations like

- [Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_(geometry)) are obviously ruled out. Further since Euler Formulae shall apply to both we get the following contradiction for expansion:
  Initially we have $3v=2e$. Then by expansion $v\mapsto 2e $ and $ e \mapsto 4e$. therefore we get
  $$
  3\cdot 2e\neq 2\cdot 4e
  $$
- Chamfering would be valid since $v\mapsto v+2e$ and $e\mapsto 4e$ leads to
  $$
  3(v+2e)=2\cdot4e\\
  3v+6e=8e\\
  3v=2e $$

Generalizing this approach to linear transformations we get:
$$
v\mapsto\mathfrak V(v,e,f)=Av+Be+Cf\\
e\mapsto\mathfrak E(v,e,f)=Dv+Ee+Ff\\
f\mapsto\mathfrak F(v,e,f)=Gv+He+Jf\\
$$

- $3$-regularity constraints:
  $$
  3(Av+Be+Cf)=2(Dv+Ee+Ff)\\
  \underbrace{(3A-2D)}_3 v+\underbrace{(3B-2E)}_{-2}e+\underbrace{(3C-2F)}_0f=0,
  $$
- constraints for embedding of graph on orientable surface with $g$ holes:
  $$
  (Av+Be+Cf)+(Gv+He+Jf)=(Dv+Ee+Ff)+2-2g\\
  \underbrace{(A+G-D)}_1v+\underbrace{(B+H-E)}_{-1}e+\underbrace{(C+J-F)}_1f=2-2g\\
  $$
- I'd also like to point out the relation between $(n,m)$ and $v,e$ and $f$, which is the following for octahedral polyhedra:
  $$
  \begin{array}{rcl}
  v&=&8T\\
  e&=&12T\\
  f&=&4T+2\\
  T&=&m^2+nm+n^2
  \end{array},
  $$
  where $T$ is the triangulation number.

Maybe it would shed some light on first question if there is an answer to the following one:

> Which transformations act invariant on the set of bicubic planar graphs and how do their linear representations looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Any non-negative integers $(n,m)$, not both zero, are valid.

["Geodesic Grids" on Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Geodesic_Grids) goes into some detail about how to construct a geodesic grid (the dual to a Goldberg polyhedron) for any values of $n$ and $m$.

Goldberg's original article, ["A Class of Multi-Symmetric Polyhedra"](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tmj1911/43/0/43_0_104/_article), also describes how to construct an icosahedral Goldberg polyhedron for any $n$ and $m$, and at the end notes that it works also for tetrahedral or cubic symmetry.

Comment: Isn't GP(0,0) just the hexagon tiling of the plane (which is an infinite large sphere)?

Comment: If you want to extend the definition with that, it would seem like a fairly sensible meaning, but it's not there by default. Such a tilling is not a polyhedron, and is not constructed like all other examples by filling in triangular patches of hexagons between six squares.

Answer (score 0):

With the 3-regularity- and the embedding- constraint, mentioned above, we can narrow down valid [transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation#Matrix_representation), such that $M_x=\pmatrix{A&B&C\\D&E&F\\G&H&J}$ has the following structure:
$$
M_x=\pmatrix{A&B&C\\\frac32(A-1)&\frac32B+1&\frac32C\\\frac12(A-1)&\frac12B&\frac12C+1}
$$

This result is supported

1. by the identity operation with:
   $$
   M_c=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}
   $$
2. by the chamfer operation with:
   $$
   M_c=\pmatrix{1&2&0\\0&4&0\\0&1&1}
   $$
3. and by the whirl operation with:
   $$
   M_c=\pmatrix{1&4&0\\0&7&0\\0&2&1}
   $$

all these leave 3-regularity invariant...