# Describe the solution of $(3,-2)\cdot \left( \pmatrix{c\\z} + \pmatrix{a&b\\x&y} \pmatrix{v\\e} \right)=0$...

Tags: linear-algebra, polyhedra

I have the following affine transformation in 2 dimensions
$$
\pmatrix{v\\e}\mapsto\pmatrix{av+be+c\\xv+ye+z}
$$
and constraints given as $3v=2e$ and therefore $3(av+be+z)=2(xv+ye+z)$. All variables and parameters are elements of $\mathbb N_0$. I can rewrite this as:
$\underbrace{(3a-2x)}_3v+\underbrace{(3c-2z)}_0=\underbrace{(2y-3b)}_2e$.
Written using matrices this gets:
$$
(3,-2)\cdot \left( \pmatrix{c\\z} + \pmatrix{a&b\\x&y} \pmatrix{v\\e} \right)=0
$$

How to (graphically?) describe the set of solution when $v$ and $e$ are fixed, i.e. in terms of $a,b,c,x,y,z$? Obviously there is an orthogonality involved.

The question is [motivated by polyhedra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2304262/19341), so the example is the [chamfer operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation#Extended_operators)
$$
(3,-2)\cdot \left( \pmatrix{0\\0} + \pmatrix{1&2\\0&4} \pmatrix{v\\e} \right)=3v+6e-8e=0\rightarrow3v=2e 
$$

Setting $c=z=0$ the question boils down to $"$Which matrices fulfill
$$
(3,-2)\cdot \pmatrix{a&b\\x&y} \pmatrix{2\\3}=0\\
6a+9b-4x-6y=0?\text{"}
$$

Looks like $ \pmatrix{2\\3}$ should be an eigenvector of $\pmatrix{a&b\\x&y}$ in this case...

Comment: Many thins you write don't make sense to me. You have a constraint $3v=2e$ on the domain of definition of the transformation? You really want to apply the transformation only on one line?

Next you apply the $3:2$ relationship constraint to the image of the transformation, what does not need to hold.

Please try to correct or clarify these points.

Comment: @wonko yes the affine transformation is applied only to one line. The important point is the transformation itself. Nominal anmial answers the question perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this from a vector algebra viewpoint. We have
$$\mathbf{R} = \left ( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ x & y \end{matrix} \right ) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
as the transformation matrix. Logically,
$$\vec{e}_1 = ( a ,\, x ) \tag{2}\label{2}$$
and
$$\vec{e}_2 = ( b ,\, y ) \tag{3}\label{3}$$
define the axes in the new coordinate system. We also have $\vec{p} = ( v , e )$ with $3 v = 2 e$, i.e. $e = 3/2 v$. If we use $w = v/2$, then 
$$\vec{p} = ( 2 w ,\, 3 w ) \tag{4}\label{4}$$
and
$$\vec{q} = ( c ,\, z ) \tag{5}\label{5}$$
and finally
$$\vec{r} = ( 3 ,\, -2 ) \tag{6}\label{6}$$

All scalars above are nonnegative integers, i.e. $a , b , c , e , v , w , x , y , z \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

---

Using equations $\eqref{1}$, $\eqref{4}$, $\eqref{5}$, and $\eqref{6}$ we have OP's equation we wish to describe:
$$\vec{r} \cdot \left ( \vec{q} + \mathbf{R} \vec{p} \right ) = 0 \tag{7}\label{7}$$

Note that $\eqref{7}$ is equivalent to
$$(6 a + 9 b - 4 x - 6 y) w + 3 c - 2 z = 0 \tag{8}\label{8}$$
which yields a pretty straightforward description of the relationship between a constant $w$ and variables $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Note that this also shows that $w = 0$ (i.e. $v = e = 0$) is a special case: If $w = 0$, then the equation simplifies to $3 c = 2 z$, and the values of $a$, $b$, $x$, and $y$ are irrelevant, i.e. matrix $\mathbf{R}$ becomes irrelevant.

Using vector algebra, if we use $\vec{r}_1 = (a , b)$, $\vec{r}_2 = (x , y)$, and $\vec{q} = (c , z)$, then we have
$$\vec{p} \cdot \left( 3 \vec{r}_1 - 2 \vec{r}_2 \right ) + \vec{q} \cdot \vec{r} = 0$$
or, moving the dot product to the other side,
$$\vec{p} \cdot \left( 2 \vec{r}_2 - 3 \vec{r}_1 \right ) = \vec{q} \cdot \vec{r} \tag{9}\label{9}$$

This means that the projection of $\vec{p}$ to vector $(2\vec{r}_2 - 3\vec{r}_1)$ matches $\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}$:
[image: Projection of vector p to vector (2r_2 - 3r_1)]
where
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\vec{p} &=& ( 2 w , 3 w ) = ( v , e ) \\
\vec{q} \cdot \vec{r} &=& 3 c - 2 z \\
2\vec{r}_2 - 3\vec{r}_1 &=& ( 2 x - 3 a , 2 y - 3 b )
\end{array}$$

Note that because $\vec{r}$ has a negative second component, $(2\vec{r}_2 - 3\vec{r}_1)$ must have integer ($\mathbb{Z}$) coordinates; they can be negative.

I find this interpretation very interesting, because it basically simplifies the transformation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ into a simple linear combination of its row vectors $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$.

---

If we use
$$\vec{q} = \vec{p}_0 - \mathbf{R}^{-1} \vec{p}_0$$
we can write equation $\eqref{7}$ as
$$\vec{r} \cdot \left ( \vec{p}_0 + \mathbf{R} ( \vec{p} - \vec{p}_0 ) \right ) = 0 \tag{10}\label{10}$$
which can then be described as:

*Vector $\vec{r}$ must be orthogonal to vector $\vec{p}$ transformed by $\mathbf{R}$ around point $\vec{p}_0$.*

(But, note that $\vec{p}_0$ does not need to have integer or positive coordinates.)

I'm not sure this is an useful description, but it is interesting because vectors $\vec{r}$, $\vec{p}$, and matrix $\mathbf{R}$ vectors $\vec{e}_1$ and $\vec{e}_2$, are all in the positive quadrant of an integer lattice.

---

> Which matrices $\mathbf{R}$ fulfill $6 a + 9 b − 4 x − 6 y = 0$?

We can solve that for any one of the variables. For example,
$$a = y - \frac{3}{2} b + \frac{2}{3} x \tag{11}\label{11}$$
which tells us that since $a, b, x, y \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $2 x / 3 + 3 b / 2$ must be a nonnegative integer not greater than $y$. That means $b$ must be even, and $x$ a a multiple of three.

So, if we change to different variables $$\begin{cases}i = x / 3\\ j = y \\ k = b / 2\end{cases}$$
then we can write all suitable matrices as
$$\mathbf{R} = \left ( \begin{matrix} 2 i + j - 3 k & 2 k \\ 3 i & j \end{matrix} \right ), \qquad \begin{cases}
i, j, k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \\
i + j \gt 0 \\
3 k \lt 2 i + j \end{cases}$$
where the requirement $i + j \gt 0$ ensures that the second row vector is not a null vector, and the $\lt$ ensures that the first row vector is not a null vector. (I am not completely certain whether degenerate $\mathbf{R}$ should be excluded, but I am assuming so.)

Comment: I'm having trouble with your $\vec p=\pmatrix{3v\\2v}$. I think it should be$\frac12 \pmatrix{2v\\2e}=\pmatrix{2v\\3v}$...? Concerning your $\mathbf{R}$: Cool, this would mean that outer diagonals are even or multiples of $3$. I'll check that...

Comment: @draks...: You're absolutely right. I've fixed it now; took some extensive editing. I've also removed the ambiguity wrt. $v$ by using $w = v/2$ instead. Because $2w$ and $3w$ must be integers, this means $v$ must be even. I also expanded a bit on the case $v = e = 0$, in which case the entire $\mathbf{R}$ is irrelevant; I consider that a degenerate case.

Comment: @draks...: With re. graphical interpretation: since $\vec{p} = (v, e) = (2w, 3w)$, $\vec{r} = ( 3, -2 )$, $\vec{q} = ( c , z ) $, and the matrix simplifies to a vector $\vec{t} = (2 x - 3 a ,\,  2 y - 3 b )$, my image shows that $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{t} = \vec{q} \cdot \vec{r}$. This shows an interesting relationship between the direction and length of $\vec{t}$ with respect to constant $\vec{p}$, and the direction and length of $\vec{q}$ with respect to constant vector $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Since $(3,-2)\cdot \pmatrix{2\\3}=0$, the latter is an eigenvector of $\pmatrix{a&b\\x&y}$, right? Can this help to structure the problem and how?

Comment: @draks...: Since my solution simplifies $\mathbf{R}$ to a vector $( 2 x - 3 a ,\, 2 y - 3 b )$, it means that it's not $\mathbf{R}$ that you need to examine, but $$\left ( \left [ \begin{matrix} -3 & 2 \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ x & y \end{matrix} \right ] \right )^T = \left [ \begin{matrix} 2 x - 3 a \\ 2 y - 3 b \end{matrix} \right ]$$i.e, the vector $\vec{t} = ( 2 x - 3 a , 2 y - 3 b )$.