# Goldberg polyhedron with a hexagon diameter

Tags: spheres, polyhedra

We say that a goldberg polyhedron $\operatorname{GP}(m,n)$ has a hexagon diameter if, in spherical form, there is a diameter of the sphere that only intersects hexagons, and goes through the center of any hexagon it intersects. For which $m$ and $n$ does $\operatorname{GP}(m,n)$ have a hexagon diameter?

Observations:

- For $k \in \mathbb Z$, it appears that $\operatorname{GP}(2k,0)$ is an example and $\operatorname{GP}(2k+1,0)$ is not, ($\operatorname{GP}(2k+1,0)$ has a diameter going through hexagons only, but it doesn't go through their centers).
- If $\operatorname{GP}(m,n)$ is an example, then so is $\operatorname{GP}(n,m)$.

(The reason I'm wondering is I'm trying to make a board game a projective sphere, and hemisphere where the diameter is all tiles is easier to use.)

Comment: For what it's worth, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304262/what-are-valid-goldberg-polyhedra-frequencies?rq=1) only asked what parameters are valid for Goldberg polyhedra, and got no response. Perhaps someone can find a family or two of the type you're after, but I'd be surprised if you get a complete characterization.

Comment: @pjs36: It's answered now ;-) (any parameters are valid.)